# Pandas dataframe from list of array and multiple array

Tags: python, pandas

Currently, I create separate `df` and finally concat these `df` to create a single `dataframe`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

blist_l=['a','b','c','d','e']
nlabel_l=['dis_label']
rt_l=['re','rq']
N=100
nlist=[np.random.rand(5) for _ in range(N)]

nlabel=np.random.randint(3,size=N)
rt=np.random.rand(N,2)
df1=pd.DataFrame(nlist,columns=blist_l)
df2=pd.DataFrame(nlabel,columns=nlabel_l)
df3=pd.DataFrame(rt,columns=rt_l)

df=pd.concat([df2,df3,df1],axis=1)
```

Is there elegant or one liner to create a df from a list of array, and, multiple array.

Comment: you can create a dictionary of columns and use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows but it is not exactly really what I would call clean code:

```
N=100
nlist=[np.random.rand(5) for _ in range(N)]

pd.DataFrame(
    {'dis_label' : np.random.randint(3,size=N)} |
     dict(zip(['re','rq'], np.random.rand(N,2).T)) |
     dict(zip(['a','b','c','d','e'], np.array(nlist).reshape(-1,N)))
)
```